# how to print right thing in 'a' when loop 'b'

Tags: python, loops

this is my code :

```
a ={
        'power':'力',
        'magic':'魔',
        'skill':'技'
    }
b =['power','wwwww']
for i in b :
    #print getattr(a,i)
    print a[i] or 'default string'
```

and it show error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 13, in <module>
    print a[i] or 'default string'
KeyError: 'wwwww'
```

how to print right thing in 'a' when loop 'b' , and show a default string when 'a' dont has it,

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use .get()

```
for i in b:
    print a.get(i, "default string")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [*conditional expression*](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions):

```
print a[i] if i in a else 'default string'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if i in a:
  st = a[i]
else:
  st = "default string"
print st
```